# host.docker.internal is failed to connect in Oracle VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine, docker-machine, hyper-v

I have application installed in VM (centOS7) running on Oracle Virtual box  with "Bridge Network" while communicating internal containers using : **http://host.docker.internal:6001(other container port) it is throwing error saying #**

request to **http://host.docker.internal** failed, reason: ETIMEDOUT 172.17.0.1:6001"

where as the same application while running in local I am able to connect to : **http://host.docker.internal.**

please help

my docker compose file

```
services:
  configuration-service:
    image: configuration-service:latest
    restart: always
    env_file: configuration-service.env
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  dose-sheet-anonymizer-rs:
    image: anonymizer-rs:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

env file:

```
anoymizer-host=http://host.docker.internal:6001
```

Comment: Which container is making this call, and what is it trying to call out to?  It sort of looks like one container is trying to call the other, and you don't need `host.docker.internal` for that.

Comment: Hi David,
thank for your reply. As per the code # configuration-service --> is trying to make call to dose-sheet-anonymizer container, and can you please guide what is the alternative.

Comment: I resolved this using Docker: Network